# custom types taxonomy hide_empty

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom type, which uses custom taxonomy to create categories. I can add 'products' and assign them to the category structure that I have created.

There is a top level menu which displays the parent categories, clicking each takes the user into the category hierarchy.

If there are no products in any sub-category of a parent category, then that listitem shouldn't display in the top level nav.

If I set hide_empty=1 *all* the parent categories disappear, not just the one with no products. Can anyone advise?

Comment: What function do you use to list products (custom taxonomy)?

Comment: get_terms() I tried pasting code in this comment but it came out looking scrambled!

Comment: Paste the code, then hit the {} button in the editor. Otherwise, you need a blank line before the codebit, and 4 (or more) spaces before each line of code to manually add it.

Comment: I also suggest using `'pad_counts' => true`. This will allow empty top level terms to appear if child terms have items.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 'hierarchical' to true if its not already.

From source documentation:

> - hierarchical - Whether to include terms that have non-empty descendants
> - (even if 'hide_empty' is set to true).

I think its usually set to trie by default, so I'm thinking you might have intentionally set it to fale for your purposes.

Comment: I think you are right - thanks for the reminder. hierarchical should be true by default and I'm not setting it